# Time-aware layers WCS Service?

Tags: arcgis-server, google-maps, time, arcgis-flex-viewer, wcs

I am currently developing an application that requires to display raster images over a period of time (I'm looking how Hurrican Sandy progressed). While investigating, people have suggested that I could use a WCS service and view it on a viewer. We are currently using Google Maps API.

My question is, how can I publish these rasters in a WCS service (or relevant format) that can allow a viewer to loop through all images. Is there a standard practice everyone follows to accomplish this?

I have knowledge using ArcGIS 9.3 Desktop/Server, ArcGIS Flex Viewer, and QGIS.

I appreciate any information regarding this topic or tutorials (haven't found any good ones yet). The images are geotiffs.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that you might actually want a WMS rather than a WCS (since you say raster images rather that raster data, and are currently using Google maps).

If all you want to do is display the images over time (using a slider or some such to control the time) then Openlayers and almost any WMS (GeoServer, MapServer, ArcGIS Server etc.) will handle this.

See these [openlayers](http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/mpriour/temporal_map/openlayers/examples/time-control.html)  [example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wmst.html) (which could use some UI love but shows the idea).

(The first example depends on this openlayers addin: https://github.com/mpriour/TimeManager_OpenLayers-Addin )

Answer (score 1):

You might look at this weather widget.  I know they load separate layers for each image and play through those layers to get the effect you are talking about. 
[Flex 2.1 - 3.0 weather widget on arcgis.com](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=75d3bf48976c44ef986a70e0dcad0f75).
And for flex 3.1 [weather widget on arcgis.com](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f6bf35d7e7dc4db697f9718fd1b2b53f). 
+1 iant for WMS. That is what is used here.

Answer (score 1):

The Flex Viewer's Time Widget supports this - see sample at http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/flex-viewer/live/index.html?config=apps/config-timeslider.xml or doc at http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/flex-viewer/concepts/index.html#/Time_widget/01m30000003n000000/

There are also several API "time" samples, for example http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/flex-api/samples/index.html#/Time_aware_Image_service/01nq0000004p000000/